# Best practice when a theme already has a parent theme (so can't create child theme)

Tags: child-theme

I've recently purchased a theme which is already has a parent theme as part of the installation (which means I can't create a child theme myself). I understand that it's best practice to create a child theme if you want to do custom modifications (to prevent the theme breaking when you run updates).

What would anyone recommend I do in this situation? Should I look for another theme that doesn't already have a parent theme or is there some way I can still make this workable with customisations?

Comment: It depends on nature of the customizations you want to apply. You can't create a child theme of a child. In some instances like this, the theme author will have best practices for you (such as Genesis framework), so check with their support. If your customizations are non-theme related, [set up a site specific plugin](https://wpbitz.com/how-to-create-a-site-specific-plugin/).

Comment: if the child theme can not be updated automatically, you can edit the files of the child theme.

Comment: The theme developers have recommended I just edit on the theme directly (the theme I'm using is already a child theme of another theme it came with). Does that sound like a good approach or will it likely cause issues?